# Python - use Selenium to login a forum

Tags: python, selenium

Hello all…I am trying to use Selenium and PhantomJS to do a headless browsing. It’s to login a forum.

What I do is, recorded the login steps in FireFox then edit it to fit PhantomJS, as below:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
base_url = "http://6atxfootball.vbulletin.net/"
verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True

driver.get(base_url)

driver.find_element_by_id("lnkLoginSignupMenu").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("idLoginUserName").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("idLoginUserName").send_keys("USERNAME_HERE")
driver.find_element_by_id("idLoginPassword").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("idLoginPassword").send_keys("PASSWORD_HERE ")
driver.find_element_by_id("idLoginBtn").click()
```

It failed and problem lies in this line, and the error is “NoSuchElementException:” etc.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("idLoginUserName").clear()
```

does this mean there’s no such an element when it’s opened by PhantomJS()? Or in a nut shell, this is not a way to do headless browsing?

Thanks.

p.s. so I tried to save the content also by PhantomJS() as a file and see what’s happening:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
base_url = "http://6atxfootball.vbulletin.net/"
verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True

driver.get(base_url)
content=driver.page_source
cleaner=clean.Cleaner()
content=cleaner.clean_html(content)    

with open('6atxfootball.html','w') as f:
   f.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
   doc=LH.fromstring(content)
```

the “6atxfootball.html” shows there isn’t any form to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because it's actually inside an iframe, so it would not be surprising that PhantomJS have some difficulties to find your element. You should try to directly log in to the url of the iframe, that is http://6atxfootball.vbulletin.net/auth/login-form

Comment: thanks, Sébastien. it's wonderful. but how do i know/find out the real form is http://6atxfootball.vbulletin.net/auth/login-form?

Comment: If you look at the source code of the homepage, you'll see the iframe and the url it links to. So you can just take the `src` attribute of the iframe whose id is `idLoginIframe`

Comment: thanks again, Sébastien. this is very interesting. what other ways, than iFrame, can a website have to have "hidden" forms?

Comment: because I am also looking at http://www.vietvbb.vn/up/index.php, but cannot find the actual login page in Iframe..

Comment: press ctrl+shift+i (or whatever) to get the dev tools up in your browser. ON the network tab, what the requests get sent when you POST your form data. You should be able to get what you need from there

Comment: thanks Paul Collingwood. Am I right that this way may be more useful to the back end way, i.e using for example Mechanize etc to simulate POST behavior, other than Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

The `NoSuchElementException` means that the element wasn't found on that page. It could mean 2 things:

1. There is really no such element on the page
2. The page is still loading and you check too early

Many times, the main page will load but parts of it will take longer time to load.
The way to avoid that is setting proper timeouts. Again, You have 2 options:

1. Explicit wait - where you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.
2. Implicit way - tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

You can read more about that [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html).